# MongoDB : How can i insert a javascript array with PHP (instead of an object)?

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$update = $col->update(array('_id' => 'test'), array('$push' => array('friends' => 1)), array('safe' => true, 'upsert' => true));
$test = $col->findOne(array('_id' => 'test'));
debug(compact('update', 'test'));
```

Does not work as expected.

I get (checking via RockMongo) :

```
{
   "_id": "test",
   "friends": {
     "0": 1 
   } 
}
```

I want/expect to have this :

```
{
   "_id": "test",
   "friends": [
     1 
   ] 
}
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: How about `array('friends' => array(1))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I spent a good amount of time a while back troubleshooting why my data was getting inserted wrongly only to find out that RockMongo doesn't *show* the data correctly.

It's belive its because RockMongo isn't really showing the data as a Mongo document, but instead as PHP.

I found this to differ for a couple of different datatypes between firefox and chrome for some reason ... arrays, dates, MongoID's

But in the end, I did a **find()** on the command line and it *was* correct.

I wouldn't trust what RockMongo is telling you, see an example below.

*Also is there a reason you need to use "safe" ?*

**Actual Data**

[image]

**What RockMongo says (wrong)**

[image]

Comment: Should have thought of that! Just used safe for debug purposes (waiting for return, etc). Thanks.

Comment: Also *@olouv*, you want to be aware of some craziness with PHP and arrays vs JSON objects. I have an example here from a presentation I did, https://github.com/gatesvp/php_get_started/blob/master/step10.php